# Excel - VBA : make Match method less restrictive (by finding a word in a sentence)

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the match function in my excel program but I have a problem with it as **it only selects the identical matches**. For example, if you compare a cell with "Banana" to another cell with "Banana", it's gonna work and return a positive value.
But if you compare "Banana" to a cell whose content is "Banana choco", then it's not gonna recognize that the word banana is in the cell.

In my case, I would like to return a TRUE value whenever a word is spotted in a sentence.

Here is my code :

```
Worksheets("sBldgMakati").Activate

For i = 2 To 605
  Range("B" & i).Activate
  myResult = IsNumeric(Application.Match(ActiveCell.Value, elementsListRange, 0))

   If myResult Then
   Range("K" & i).Value = Range("K" & i).Value + 10
   Else
   Range("K" & i).Value = Range("K" & i).Value + 0
End If

Next i
```

I have to specify that in this code, `elementsListRange` correspond to a range of cells whose content is only one word ("Banana" for example) and the `ActiveCell.value` is usually a longer expression ("Banana choco" for example).

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Have you tried using the `Find` or `Search` functions? And is `elementsListRange` a range of cells, of a VBA list/collection of cell values?

Comment: maybe u could select an answer on all your questions, it's the reason we do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following function, it matches a substring within a string:

```
Function match(searchStr As Variant, matchStr As Variant) As Boolean
    match = False
    If (IsNull(searchStr) Or IsNull(matchStr)) Then Exit Function
    If (matchStr = "") Or (searchStr = "") Then Exit Function
    Dim f As Variant
    f = InStr(1, CStr(searchStr), CStr(matchStr), vbTextCompare)
    If IsNull(f) Then Exit Function
    match = f > 0
End Function
```

To use it with a range:

```
Dim searchstr="A Banana found"
Dim isFound as boolean
IsFound=false
For each c in range
    If match(searchstr, c.value) 
         IsFound=true
         Exit for
    End if
End for
```

**Note** that `searchStr` and `matchStr` are variant so you can pass values from Excel cells to it.

Answer (score 5):

From the help documentation in Excel (if you press F1 and search for `match`):

> If match_type is 0 and lookup_value is a text string, you can use the 
>   wildcard characters — the question mark (?) and asterisk (*) — in the 
>   lookup_value argument. A question mark matches any single character; 
>   an asterisk matches any sequence of characters.

Thus, `=MATCH("*Banana*",C8,0)` returns `1` if `C8` contains `"Banana choco"`.

In VBA, if the item to be matched is in a cell, you can include the wildcard asterisks with string concatenation, e.g.:

```
myResult = IsNumeric(Application.Match("*" & ActiveCell.Value & "*", elementsListRange, 0))
```

If there are many sentences in the range `B2:B605` that have to be tested against all the words in `elementListRange`, as appear to be the case in this situation, I think you may need to do something like this (untested):

```
For Each cell in elementsListRange.Cells
    myResult = Application.Match("*" & cell.Value & "*", B2:B605, 0)
    if (IsNumeric(myResult)) then
        Range("K" & myResult).Value = Range("K" & myResult).Value + 10
    end if
next
```

Comment: Thanks for this information @Simon, it's helpful. Nevertheless, I didn't manage to make it work in my case as I am not directly dealing with the contents of my cells but with the Range. I tried to add asterisks in my code but it's obviously not the right way. Do you know what would be the right way to put asterisks around "elementsListRange" (where "banana" would be stored in my case), but in a coding way ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how you can concatenate the asterisks on either end of the cell value.

Comment: Oh thanks, really interesting. However, I am sorry to solicit you again but as the cells with single words are stored in "elementsListRange", so it's not working to do this for ActiveCelle.Value. And addind "*" & before and after "elementsListRange" is returning an error message (incompatibility of type). I also tried directly on the content of elementsListRange but it's not working : Set elementsListRange = .Range("D2:D" & lRowD)

Comment: @Phalanx: My understanding of `Match()` is that it will search for `ActiveCell.Value` in `elementsListRange`. Thus, if you're trying to find any of the words in `elementsListRange` in `ActiveCell.Value`, then I think you'll have to loop through `elementsListRange` cell by cell and search for each of them in the string held in the active cell. I've amended my answer to try and address this.

Comment: Sorry Simon I unselected your answer as the right one as I still had "syntax" error. Matt's answer is working well for my case and gives me the result I was expected. But thanks so much anyway, I learned a lot!